# Bring focus to the original page tab a chrome extension was called on?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

- chrome extension toolbar button pressed
- opens popup which has button  and when that button is pressed it injects a `content.js` file into the current page DOM
- The `content.js` in the page build a DIV Modal window.  In that modal is a button that when pressed sends a message to chrome extensions `background.js` file to tell it to build a full page screenshot image.
- It then also hides the modal DIV from view on that page `display: none;`
- Because it is a full page height screenshot, it has to send messages back and forth between the `content.js` and `background.js` scripts with coordinates so that it will snap an image of the view port frame by frame to build a full height image.
- When the image is done building, my `background.js` script opens a new file `edit.html` which is a custom page in my extension with a full image annotation library to edit the image.
- From the `edit.html` file, when the image is done editing, it uses AJAX to upload the new image to my remote server using AJAX and returns the URL of the new image upload.
- This is where I need to close the `edit.html` file/tab and send a message back to the original pages `content.js` with the new image URL and also a message to tell it to un-hide the modal window on that page and insert the new image URL into a text input field in that modal window.

**I have all this working up until the point where I need to:**

- close the `edit.html` file/tab
- at the same time, bring focus back to the original page tab we started on
- also send a message to that original pages `content.js` script which can include a message to show the modal window and include the image URL of the screenshot we built, edited, and then uploaded to remote server.

**1)**
Any help in how to close the edit.html tab and bring focus back to the original tab page?

I believe the edit.html page will have to send a message to the `background.js` file to close itself and then that background.js file can also send a message to the original tabs content.js file and bring focus to it again.  Just not sure how to do this part.  Mainly knowing which tab was the original.

Comment: `displkay: none;` should be `display: none;` & `edit/html` should be `edit.html`;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 thanks for pointing out the typos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the content script uses `chrome.runtime.connect()` to send messages to the background page, then the background page can get the tab ID from `port.sender.tab.id` where "port" is the name of the port object. The background page can pass the tab ID to the new `edit.html` page by putting it in the search string of the URL used to open the new tab, eg. `chrome.tabs.create({url: "edit.html?23"})`. As the `edit.html` page is part of your extension it can use `chrome.tabs.update()` to focus the original page and it can close itself by using `chrome.tabs.getCurrent()` to get its own tab ID and then using `chrome.tabs.remove()`. It can send a message to the content script by either using `chrome.tabs.sendMessage()` or by using `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` to access the window object of the background page which would enable it to use an existing message port between the background page and the content script.

Comment: Thanks I think I got it figured out now =)